# Textmate-like autocomplete for VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, textmate

Textmate has an extremely simple yet very convenient feature: https://macromates.com/blog/2012/clever-completion/

Basically, it's an in-place autocomplete by "Esc" using words (symbols) from open document(s), sorted by distance, with looping through alternative results by repeated keypress... So simple, yet extremely convenient and comfortable. No dropdown suggestions (important part), no "smart" suggestions, no method/property/attribute lookup, just dumb and simple inline loop-over autocomplete from words in the document.

Can anyone recommend an extension for VSCode that does just that? I was not able to find an extensions that mimics such feature and I miss it very much.

Comment: you can write it yourself, and I would say to choose a different key then `Esc` because it would be hard to find a when clause that will work because `Esc` does a lot of things